# PHP upload temp files sometimes remains

Tags: php

Official Document says that "The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed."

In my testing, most of time yes, but sometimes the temp files remains.

My server accept files, and NOT use move_uploaded_file(). Instead using CurlFile upload the temp file to another server immediately.

I checked FPM log, no process died. So in theory the FPM should always delete the temp file when the script finished.

So what could be the possibilitity sometimes the temp files remains?

Comment: May you show your code?

Comment: @neoascetic my code has much encapsulation, may not represent much information, but the flow is as the topic described. Key point is I did not rename or move the temp file. And the process never died or coredump, but the temp file remains~

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of race condition? File is locked by curl and, thus, cannot be deleted by php at cleanup stage?

Comment: @neoascetic may be... I tried to add an explicit unlink right after the curl upload, and the temp files which remain reduced, but still exist~